# How to fix 'relation "us_lex" does not exist' using standardize_address?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, street-address, addressing

I'm trying to parse a column of ~175,000 street names. Some of them are just one word (Jamaicaway), and some are multiple words (St. Edwards Pl). I want just the street body (Jamaicaway and St. Edwards, respectively).

I found the address_standardizer package and installed it, but when I run the example below I get the error relation "us_lex" does not exist.

```
    SELECT house_num, name, suftype, city, country, state, unit
    FROM standardize_address('us_lex', 'us_gaz', 'us_rules', 'One 
        Devonshire Place, PH 301, Boston, MA 02109');
```

I'd expect to get back just "Devonshire," but I'm getting the error instead. There doesn't seem to be much about this on the [package page](http://postgis.net/docs/Address_Standardizer.html). Any insight?

Comment: have you also installed the data extension? `CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;`

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to run:

CREATE EXTENSION address_standardizer_data_us;

Which creates the us_lex and other data tables

Comment: Please reserve the Answer field for a complete solution that is also useful for other users of the site. If you have additions, or suggestions, post them as a comment instead.

Comment: Sorry, if I don’t understand, but isn’t what I posted above a complete solution to the user’s problem?